# apt-get failed to fetch error

Tags: linux, apt-get, backtrack-linux

I am trying to use `apt-get`. I run the following command

`apt-get update`

But I get this error

```
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release.gpg                                                                                                                           
  Could not connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (37.221.173.214). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                               
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/microverse Translation-en_US                                                                                                         
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/non-free Translation-en_US                                                                                                           
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/testing Translation-en_US                                                                                                            
  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release.gpg                                                                                                                            
  Could not connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (37.221.173.214). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main Translation-en_US                                                             
  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/microverse Translation-en_US                                                       
  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/non-free Translation-en_US                                                         
  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/testing Translation-en_US                                                          
  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org revolution Release.gpg                                                                     
  Could not connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (37.221.173.214). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main Translation-en_US                                                         
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/microverse Translation-en_US                                                   
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/non-free Translation-en_US                                                     
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Err http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/testing Translation-en_US                                                      
  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                               
W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release.gpg  Could not connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (37.221.173.214). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/microverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/testing/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to all.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release.gpg  Could not connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (37.221.173.214). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/microverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/testing/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to 64.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release.gpg  Could not connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:80 (37.221.173.214). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/microverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/testing/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to source.repository.backtrack-linux.org:http:

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone know what's the problem??
I'm using vmware player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option

[all.repository.backtrack-linux.org](http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org) is unreachable (try it in your browser)

Second option

The problem is that your virtual machine doesn't have a correct network configuration.

apt-get can't connect to the network.

To verify it try :

```
ping www.google.com
```

If it doesn't print results within seconds then you have no internet connection in your virtual machine.

Look [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_bridged.html) for network configuration

By default, Bridged Networking should be enabled and working out of the box. Check your VmWare configuration. Otherwise instructions about setting network configuration in general are detailled in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it has proper connection i think. I can browse the net from it actually. And when I did `ping www.google.com` it gave me `4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 80.747/86.954/93.536/4.618 ms` Then I just sopped the ping

Comment: Then What do I do if the repositories are unreachable?? I want to update/install some packages...!!!

Comment: I believe that's another question, if the repository you are using is not working then maybe you should contact Backtrack maintainers

Comment: he was right. That url seems invalid when i tried to open it in the browser

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the same problem couple of days a go,

The Solution:
You will need to Reset the "sources.list" file and to do that you will follow the next steps:

- Open Terminal
- Type "software-properties-gtk", Then Press Enter
- It will open the below screen for you Click the "Revert" Button on the right bottom
- Click the Close Button and then allow to to update Now Close all the windows 
  Go back to the Terminal and type "sudo apt-get update", so that you can update and it should work.

i wrote a post about with pictures, check it out here: http://saleh360.blogspot.com/2015/05/ubuntu-update-some-index-files-failed.html

Comment: Sorry, SO is not for promoting your blog. Add relevant parts of the answer here  to the answer or delete your answer.